Path Alias Not Working in Bun Project Despite Correct Configuration
I config path alias following this guide: https://bun.sh/guides/runtime/tsconfig-paths. But it's not work
I create a Bun project (I'm planning to migrate a Node app to Bun) by these steps:

mkdir bun-test && cd bun-test && bun init

After init project, I add to tsconfig.ts


{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "config": ["./src/config/appConfig.ts"]
    }
  }
}


Create src/config/appConfig.ts

export default {
  message: "My first bun application",
};


Modify src/index.ts.

import appConfig from "config";

console.log(appConfig.message);


VSCode intellisense resolve the path well, but when run app bun run ./src it throw error

error: Cannot find package "config" from "/bun-test/src/index.ts"

Bun v1.1.29 (Linux x64)

What problem here? Am i missing some step?

Please don't edit the question to include the answer. Instead write an answer in the answer section below your question

I found the answer here https://github.com/JLarky/bun-netlify (after taking half of a day to search)
Thanks for JLarky note:
When you run bun dev it will use bun just as a script runner, and your vite will actually be running in Node. But if you run bun --bun dev if will use Bun JavaScript runtime to run Vite.
My code run correctly with bun --bun run ./src
